# Replicate Java Try-Catch philosophy in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, try-catch

I come from a Java background, where try/catch is common practice.

After few months working with objective-c I have never implemented try/catch in my iOS app, because of the nature of the language itself, and general advices for not using it.

Therefore I have always tried to build error free code. But, at time of writing, I still didn't know how a simple thing like that can be translated in objective-c:

```
// some operation
try {
  // do some work
} catch (SomethingWentWrongException e) {
  // log error, inform user...etc
}
// some more operation and rest of the code
```

With this code operation around try/catch is executed, but the program is not broke, and the rest of the code after catch is executed.

However there's a rule telling that we shouldn't use try catch for flow control.
I would like to implement something similar with objective-c, encapsulate some less important operations that may succeed or not, without breaking the workflow.

How can I do that without objective-c @try ?

thanks

Comment: As Graham says, there's nothing keeping you from using the Objective-C throw/try/catch mechanism.  But it's a kind of half-hearted attempt at exceptions in a return-code-based environment, so don't expect it to be nearly as seamless as in Java.

Comment: I'd be interested to know in what way ObjC exceptions are "half-hearted", @hotlicks.

Comment: @GrahamLee -- I mean the mechanism is there, but not really intended to be used.

Comment: If they didn't want anyone using it it wouldn't exist (as indeed it didn't until about 2005)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You *can* do that with Objective-C using `@try` and `@catch` (and `@finally`). There's no "rule" that says you don't, but there *is* a pervasive design idiom throughout Cocoa and code build to integrate with Cocoa: exceptions are reserved for programmer error. That means if the person using your API doesn't honour the contract, or doesn't satisfy some preconditions for calling your methods, *that* is the only time that many Objective-C developers would use exceptions.

The common idiom for handling errors (e.g. my file went away, I couldn't get the resource I needed etc) in Objective-C code is to use Cocoa's NSError class, passing an instance by reference to the method that could possibly fail. So, rewriting your example:

```
// some operation
NSError *error;
BOOL itWorked = [object doSomeThingThatCouldFail: &error];
if (!itWorked) {
    // log error, inform user etc.
}
// some more operation and rest of the code
```

Notice that you check the *return value* of the method to check whether it succeeded or failed. The `error` object is guaranteed to be set on failure, but no promise is made about it on success.

The way the implementation of the method works with the error:

```
- (BOOL)doSomeThingThatCouldFail: (NSError *__autoreleasing*)error {
  //...
  if (!success && error) //check that the user actually supplied an error pointer
  {
    NSDictionary *errorDetails = @{ ... };
    *error = [NSError errorWithDomain: @"Your error domain" code: someInteger userInfo: errorDetails];
  }
  return success;
}
```

Comment: Spot on. I want to see people using `NSError` like this more often, and I will give my reputation up arrows to anybody who evangelizes it! :)

Comment: thanks, the concept is quite clear, however it is not clear how could I write a method that fill error in case of...error.

Comment: @leonardo first check the pointer is not NULL, as callers don't need to set it. Then `*error = [NSError errorWith…];`

Answer (score 0):

Kind of off topic, but an idiom I've used successfully in several situations where one may need to "abort" an operation in the middle of a series of sub-operations is the following:

```
int rcode = 0;
do {
    rcode = operationA(xxx);
    if (rcode) break;
    rcode = operationB(xxx);
    if (rcode) break;
    ...
    rcode = operationZ(xxx);
    if (rcode) break;
} while (FALSE);

if (rcode) {
    <do recovery/error-reporting stuff>
}
else {
    <do stuff you'd do if successful>
}
```

Kind of a poor-man's try/catch -- Avoids the spaghetti logic you'd have if you tried to have an entire if/then/else around each individual operation.  (Obviously, you can optionally set some state variables at each step, to know how far you got, what are the reasons for the error, etc.)

Comment: Except that `try`/`catch` exist in Objective-C as `@try`/`@catch`. Though (as Graham explains) exceptions in Objective-C are reserved for programmer error rather than all error handling.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- But like I said above it's a half-hearted implementation, and nothing really makes it easy to use -- you basically have to check RC and throw exception at each API call.  The above gives some of the "cleanness" of a simple try/catch in a return code environment.

Comment: Generally speaking, in Objective-C you never use `@try` and `@catch`, and only use `@throw` to indicate that the guy who called your code screwed up. So no, you wouldn't be throwing an exception at each API call.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- So you wouldn't be duplicating Java's functionality.

Comment: You could, but it's not the Objective-C way.

Comment: @JonathanGrynspan -- Which is why I suggested the above -- it works in an Obj-C environment but gives you the "quick out" function of try/catch.

Comment: @Hot Licks: Is `leave` an Objective-C keyword? Or did you mean to use `continue` or `break`?

Comment: @echristopherson -- Ah!! I meant `break`, though `continue` will work as well.  Too many different languages whirling around in my head.